# BitmapImage to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage, imagesource

I have a `BitmapImage` that I'm using in a WPF application, I later want to save it to a database as a byte array (I guess it's the best way), how can I perform this conversion?

Or, alternatively, is there a better way to save a `BitmapImage` (or any of its base classes, `BitmapSource` or `ImageSource`) to a data repository?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To convert to a byte[] you can use a MemoryStream:

```
byte[] data;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Instead of the JpegBitmapEncoder you can use whatever BitmapEncoder you like as casperOne said.

If you are using MS SQL you could also use a `image`-Column as MS SQL supports that datatype, but you still would need to convert the BitmapImage somehow.

Comment: This works if I've loaded my image in using the UriSource, but if I load it in from a memory stream, at encoder.Save(ms), I get Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

A few of the properties of ms are showing 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

Comment: @Tommy This sounds like some other problem you are facing which maybe just pops up during conversion, because it should work fine...
Maybe you can create a new question including you code to reproduce the problem and comment a link here?

Comment: @Christopher Thanks so much. I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812386/saving-a-bitmapimage-to-file-works-when-the-image-has-been-imported-from-file-b)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use an instance of a class that derives from [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) (such as [`BmpBitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bmpbitmapencoder.aspx)) and call the [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.save.aspx) method to save the `BitmapSource` to a `Stream`.

You would choose the specific encoder depending on the format you want to save the image in.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? Let's say for simplicity I want PNG (that's the format loaded into the BitmapImage).

Answer (score -1):

write it to a `MemoryStream`, then you can access the bytes from there.
something kinda like this:

```
public Byte[] ImageToByte(BitmapImage imageSource)
{
    Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
    Byte[] buffer = null;
    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I think that doesn't work if you are using UriSource to load the image, but I'm not shure...

Comment: @chrfin mmmm, dunno havn't tried it. should work fine for his WPF app, tho

Comment: My StreamSource property on the BitmapImage is null for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: @So: because you didn't load it from a stream. This isn't going to work for you.

Comment: @ChrFin:  Yes. You are correct. if we use UriSource, StreamSource would be null.

Answer (score -2):

You can give a formate of bitmap:

```
Image bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics.FromImage(bmp).CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score -7):

Just use a MemoryStream.

```
byte[] data = null;

using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmapImage.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You forgot a few steps there...
you need to use an encoder.