# Need serialize bitmap image silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wcf, serialization, bitmapimage

I need serialize custom class with bitmapImage(tagged by xmlIgnore right now).
I'm using xmlSerialization, but I think thats bad.Do you have some ideas how can I serialize my class??Probably you can provide some simple example??

```
class X
{
private BitmapImage someImage;
public BitmaImage{get;set}
}
```

Actually later I will be use WCF Service.
Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the [image as a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte), e.g.:

```
public byte[] ImageAsBytes
{
    get { return BytesFromImage(someImage); }
    set { someImage = ImageFromBytes(value); }
}
```

You can of course convert back using a stream and the [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) property.

Comment: But I can't find StreameSource at BitmapImage

Comment: @ThomasWingfield - That is probably because you are using Silverlight (next time, tag your question with the correct tags!!)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the image to a `Base64` string. Examples from [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx):

```
//Convert image to the string
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
     // Convert Image to byte[]
     image.Save(ms, format);
     byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

     // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
     string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
     return base64String;
   }
}

//when deserializing, convert the string back to an image
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
   // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
   byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);    
   // Convert byte[] to Image
   ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
   Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
   return image;
}
```

Comment: But image class in Silverlight don't have "Save" method!