# WCF Image Serializing

Tags: c#, wcf, image

I have this code in my WCF Service:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract] void SaveImage(MyImage myImg);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void SaveImage(MyImage myImg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this error occur when I run the SaveImage() method:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:e. The InnerException message was '**Type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' with data contract name 'Bitmap:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing' is not expected.** Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'

My code is in C#, Framework 4.0, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The data-contract expected `Image`, but it got a `Bitmap : Image` instance. WCF likes to know about inheritance *in advance*, so you would need to tell it. But! I honestly don't think that is a good approach; you should really just throw the raw binary around instead - which probably means saving the `Image` to a `MemoryStream` first. You should also formally decorate your contract type. I would be sending:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyImage
{
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
}
```

An example of getting the `byte[]`:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I use the Image.FromFile() method to get the image without using the Bitmap class. How can I convert Image to Byte[]?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here: [Need serialize bitmap image silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701272/need-serialize-bitmap-image-silverlight) an Image is not serializable. So you could turn the image into a byte array (of any format you like, ranging from just pixel colors to an official format such as PNG) and use that

Comment: System.Drawing.Image has a SerializableAttribute so I think it's serializable. See here for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

Comment: That attribute is not for xml serialization. WCF uses the DataContractSerializer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx which uses XML serialization.

Comment: Ok, I'll just convert it to byte[]. Thanks.