# Convert BitmapImage to Byte[] in Silverlight4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, arrays, bitmapimage

can any one has idea. how to convert BitmapImage to Byte[] in silverlight4 application
i have one image file in .xap file.

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/GRed.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

now i want to convert BitmapImage to Byte[] and save in to db as binary format.

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte

Comment: no it's not applicable in silverlight4

Answer (score 1):

```
    private byte[] ToByteArray(BitmapImage bi)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bi);
        int[] p = bmp.Pixels;
        int len = p.Length * 4;
        byte[] result = new byte[len]; 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bi); at this line it's give me a error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Is it possible the BitmapImage you are passing is null? Can you debug and make sure your code for reading in the image is not returning null?