# Convert BitmapImage or IRandomAccessStream to byte array in Windows 10 UAP

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, bitmapimage

Who can help me. I don't understand how i can convert BitmapImage or IRandomAccessStream to byte array.
I try:

```
foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
    BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        await src.SetSourceAsync(stream);

        WriteableBitmap bitMap = new WriteableBitmap(src.PixelWidth, src.PixelHeight);
        await bitMap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

then i have WriteableBitmap and try this:

```
private byte[] ImageToByeArray(WriteableBitmap wbm)
{
    using (Stream stream = wbm.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

but it's don't work for me ;(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    async Task<byte[]> Convert(IRandomAccessStream s)
    {
        var dr = new DataReader(s.GetInputStreamAt(0));
        var bytes = new byte[s.Size];
        await dr.LoadAsync((uint)s.Size);
        dr.ReadBytes(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: await dr.LoadAsync((uint)s.Size); is not working in UWP properly

Answer (score -1):

I used this solution in my WPF applications to save images in database as `byte[]`. It should also work in your case.

```
public static byte[] ImageToString(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage img) {
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource)img));
    encoder.Save(stream);
    stream.Flush();

    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: not work ;( in windows 10 uap doesn't has this classes

Comment: You cannot import System.Windows.Media.Imaging reference?

Comment: Have you tried these three solutions? [Solution1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte) - [Solution2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array) - [Solution3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array)

Comment: yes, it's don't work too..there is no classes
i also try:

var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            UInt32 width = decoder.PixelWidth;
            UInt32 height = decoder.PixelHeight;

          
            var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
               BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                new BitmapTransform(),
                ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
               ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);

            return pixels.DetachPixelData();

Comment: How you get images? [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2b75e17a-dce8-44aa-bce2-ccf5cce1a0f9/how-to-convert-a-image-to-byte-array?forum=wpdevelop) a possible solution if you use a path to images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99632/discussion-between-erikscandola-and-user3588235).