# "Cannot Cast from source type to destination type" eror thrown ; when attempting to pass data from embedded dll resource to a field

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, embedded-resource

Here is my auto generated resource class which i modify to use the `UnityEngine.Texture2D` class instead of `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

```
namespace DaiMangou.Properties {
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;

    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]


    internal class GeneralImageResources {


     internal static Texture2D ScaleHandle {
                get {
                    object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("ScaleHandle", resourceCulture);
                    return ((Texture2D)(obj));
                }
            }

}
```

Here is my other class in another script

```
public class ScaleHandle
{

public Texture2D scaleHandleTexture = DaiMangou.Properties.GeneralImageResources.ScaleHandle;

}
```

This, however throws an error

> "**InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.**"

How do I pass the `ScaleHandle` texture to my `scaleHandleTexture` field ?

The Unity Engine does not support the use of System.Drawing so I really cant use Bitmap

Comment: obviously the cast exception is thrown from the line `return ((Texture2D)(obj));` (your resource should not be of the `Texture2D` type)

Comment: thanks for letting me know. +1
I do not know how to get around that. There are comparability issues with certain platform that will use the dll. making the resource a Texture2D type was the only way around it.
How do i go about successfully passing the ScaleHandle texture to the scaleHandleTexture field.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't modify your autogenerated resource file, let them to `BitmapImage` type.

Then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte) is the code to convert `BitmapImage` to `byte[]` (warning with the part on using the right encoder for your image type):

```
byte[] data;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(DaiMangou.Properties.GeneralImageResources.ScaleHandle));
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

And Finally [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) is the code to convert to `Texture2D`:

```
Texture2D.LoadImage(data);
```

In Sum:

```
public class ScaleHandle
{
    protected static Texture2D ImageToTexture(Image srcImage)
    {
        byte[] data;
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(srcImage));
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(data);
        return tex;
    }

    public Texture2D scaleHandleTexture = ImageToTexture(DaiMangou.Properties.GeneralImageResources.ScaleHandle);
}
```

PS: I don't even know what is Unity, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: +1 for helping out so far.
I will test the code a little later on and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I could not get this to work for me , but thank you.